# Bad Access Error on XCode C++

Tags: c++, xcode

I am trying to implement a Polynomial structure using a linked list of Terms (the linked list is implemented separately).
 When I run my main program, I get a  (Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2) error on the line 
`coeff = x;` in the definition my `setCoeff` function. 
I tried commenting out that specific function call, but it gives me the same error for the setX() and setY() functions. 
I think I have my files and functions set up properly, I cannot figure out why it is not letting me use these functions. 
Please help ! 
In order, I have included: Polynomial.h, Polynomial.cpp, and main.cpp.

```
    #ifndef __Polynomial__Polynomial__
    #define __Polynomial__Polynomial__

    #include <stdio.h>

    class Term {
    private:
        int coeff;
        int deg_x;
        int deg_y;
    public:
        Term();
        int getCoeff();
        int getX();
        int getY();
        void setX(int);
        void setY(int);
        void setCoeff(int);
    };


    #endif /* defined(__Polynomial__Polynomial__) */

___________________________
#include "Polynomial.h"

Term::Term() {
    coeff = NULL;
    deg_x = NULL;
    deg_y = NULL;
}

int Term::getCoeff(){
    return coeff;
}
int Term::getX() {
    return deg_x;
}
int Term::getY() {
    return deg_y;
}
void Term::setX(int x){
    deg_x = x;
}
void Term::setY(int x){
    deg_y = x;
}
void Term::setCoeff(int x){
    coeff = x;
}
__________________________
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Polynomial.h"

int main() {
    Term* t1;
    t1->setCoeff(4);
    t1->setX(3);
    t1->setY(6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never create an object.  You have `Term* t1`, which is an uninitialized pointer to random memory, then you try to use it with `t1->setCoeff(4)` which is trying to use an object that was never created.  That's definitely gonna go wrong.

Do this instead..

```
auto t1 = std::make_unique<Term>();
```

Or if you don't need it to be a pointer, you can create a simple stack variable and access it with '.' operator like this ...

```
Term t1;
t1.setCoeff(4);
t1.setX(3);
t1.setY(6);
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even realize, such a simple mistake.. Thank you so, so much!